# How can I make the image fill the whole container?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to make the image always fill width and height.

I am using LayerSlider WP plugin so I set width 100% at its settings and also `width: 100% !important` into a field that says "custom css"

PS: This is the link http://www.draidel.com.ar/novedades (you will see I added a very small and squared image in the first slide and a wider image for the second one but still doesnt fill the full width)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the `min-height` and `min-width` of your `img` to be 100%. But, you'll also need to set its `height` and `width` to `auto` in order to preserve its aspect ratio, no matter the screen size or orientation. If you also want to centre the `img` in its parent if its height or width exceed those of its parent, then you'll need to use `position:absolute` to set its `left` and `top` positions to 50% and then use the `translate` `transform` function to pull them back by 50% again. Here's an example:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
figure{
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
img{
  display:block;
  height:auto;
  min-height:100%;
  left:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  width:auto;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<figure><img src="http://draidel.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/website-647013_1280.jpg"></figure>
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. UPDATE: by the way, any idea why the text background is not complete ? (seems to be like...cropped)

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my answer about maintaining the ratio of the image's dimensions (by setting its `height` & `width` to `auto`); if the ratio of the dimensions of the parent element is different then the image will be cropped. For my example, I chose to crop it evenly from all sides but you can crop it from any corner instead by adjusting the image's positioning properties. If I have time when I get home, I'll update my answer with a step-by-step of what I'm doing and provide you with a few different options for the cropping.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this on stylesheet file?

```
img.ls-preloaded{
width:100%!important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello !, The problem is that if you resize the window you will see how it gets deformed.

Comment: height:auto!important